# Why does my POST request throw a 503 after 30 seconds?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, browser, fetch

Why does my **POST** request fail with a **503** error after exactly **30** seconds? Is this a browser or server issue?

This fails:

```
  fetch('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e20fb8a300000b4a4d1f2af?mocky-delay=31000ms', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ test: 1 })
  })
```

This works:

```
  fetch('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e20fb8a300000b4a4d1f2af?mocky-delay=29000ms', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ test: 1 })
  })
```

I've tried Chrome and Safari. Same result.
I've tried Fetch and XMLHttpRequest. Same result.
I've tried Mocky.io API and the API at my company.

Comment: It's likely their servers or load balancer enforce a timeout on requests.

Comment: The error code comes from the server, not the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the 503 was being returned was the Load Balancer had a timeout of 30 seconds. So even if the API was returning a successful response after the 30 seconds, the load balancer returned a 503 before the API.

Comment: what is the attribute that you changed in the load balancer?