# Azure Function dies after 30 seconds and cannot run multiple invocations concurrently

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function using .NET C# consumption plan (also tested in dedicated plan), triggered by HTTP trigger, and currently I am very confusing with its behaviors

--UPDATE 3: I just realized that it seems like I only have the problem if I use the run through Azure Portal. It runs perfectly if I call it from a browser. So perhaps it is just Microsoft fault.... If it can run normally when it is called from a browser, I don't care if the Portal dies. So please concentrate on the concurrency behavior.

**First thing** is: it cannot run for more than 30 seconds.
In the below picture, you can see that, I only have a very simple Task.Delay. If I set it to lower than 30 seconds. It runs fine. But if I set it to more than 30 seconds, like what is in the picture, it will returns 503 errors.

[image]

--UPDATE: THE FULL CODE

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    var datenow = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss");

    await Task.Delay(32000);

    return new OkObjectResult("OK..." + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID") + " Start date time: " + datenow );
}
```

--UPDATE 2: You can raise the Task.Delay to 40000, so the problem can be reproduced easier. Also, if you want to reproduce, please try it multiple time, as it can success and fail randomly.

**The second weird behavior** is that the Azure Function seems to process things sequentially, while my expectation is that it should process things concurrently. For example. I call the above function, which has a task.delay of 10 second, 2 times, using 2 separated tab from my browser. I noticed that the second call only ran after the first one start
[image]

Are those above things normal. Or did I misconfigured something? What I want is that I want a function can be longer than 30 seconds, the longer the better. Also, I want functions to be concurrently run.

Note: I tried the Diagnosis and solve problem but it didn't give me any idea into this.

Comment: Line No 15 is not completely visible so paste your code in the question instead of image!

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT Sorry I added the code snippet for it. Also I tried the Diagnosis and solve problem but it didn't give me any idea.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/scQakkz.png - Its working for me. Check your function once again.

Comment: @SuryasriKamini-MT I just tested it 2 times and 1 of them successful but 1 of them failed. Can you test raising the task.delay to 40000? so that 503 error can be reproduced easier. Also, can you try running multiple times?

Comment: I have the same problem with Azure Functions when using Python as my runtime environment.  If I set a while loop for greater than 30 seconds it returns the exact same 503 message.