# Web Apps causing deployment errors with 'WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

Some of web apps from time to time fails to deploy or breaks and I end up getting a 503 error. I took out the website run from package and it ran fine but i have a lot of apps for both web and function apps and I want to know why this happened. Do I still need to use it or not? Should I still use it or not? Is the WEBSITE RUN FROM PACKAGE causing these apps to break or is there another way to fix them? Does something need to be updated in my part through settings etc? I deploy all of my apps through the azure pipeline builds. This is bothering me a lot as I dont want my pipelines to break now esp when I send out releases. Much appreciated with any insight.

Answer (score 0):

`WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` is recommended way for deployment of Function Apps if you want to deploy using ZIP deploy.

When you are running the function and If your function is returning the 503 Service Unavailable, then check the Request-Response time because there is a time limit for request processing in Azure Function Http Request i.e., 230 Seconds available in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout). In this case, either increase the timeout value or change the Hosting Plan to higher or use [async pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp-inproc#async-http) in Azure Durable Functions for long running tasks.

If you are getting the 503 Service Error unavailable post-deployment, then it will be 2 causes mainly:

1. check your function host is down or restarting state.
2. Check the memory consumption exceeded your Hosting Plan limit (Consumption Plan - Functions) and also, check the troubleshooting steps given in this SO [71658591](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71658591/azure-function-returns-503-after-30-seconds#:%7E:text=In%20Azure%20Functions%2C%20HTTP%20Error,Function%20host%20is%20down%2Frestarting.).

#### Updated Answer

I can See the bug raised in GitHub Azure Functions Repo earlier with the similar scenario that the user @*qJake* is getting 503 Service when deployed Azure Functions using Azure DevOps when using the setting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` and resolved the issue-solutions given in the ticket #[**11444**](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11444)